# Issue with filenames with special characters in database import

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding

I'm moving a clients wordpress website to a new host and importing their database. They have thousands of images, some of which have special characters (å,ä,ö) in the filenames. These images are now not working, they just lead to a 404. I've tried changing the db collation for the relevant tables/rows. I've tried uploading the images with filezilla and forcing UTF-8.

What I finally had to do to make it work is to do a str_replace on the filenames wherever they're used and replace the åäö's with the å's, ä's and ö's from the original filenames, which seems like a less than optimal solution, and it only works on the front end, and not in the wp-admin.

Is there somethong else I could do during the import to either change the filenames or change their encoding?

Comment: Do both databases have the same character set?

Comment: The old db uses utf8, the new one uses utf8mb4, the collation is utf8_general_ci on the old db and utf8mb4_swedish_ci on the new. Should I change the charset and collation or can it be done without changing it?

Comment: I think it's a basic test you could have done before anything else

Comment: I tried changing it, and I also tried changing it before the import. Still no difference.